# Regex to filter out $

Tags: c#, regex

I have a powershell script that returns the following items:

```
migration test 
TECHS-NT$
Administrator 
krbtgt
SDI$
```

Now, I want to eliminate the items that contain a $ and feed the items that do not have a $ into a list. Something like,

```
    List<string> powershellResults = new List<string>();
    foreach (string str in Powershell.Create().AddScript(PS Script))
    {
        if (Regex.IsMatch(str, @"(\w*[^$])"))
        {
            powershellResults.Add(str);
       }
    }

    foreach (string str in powershellResults)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
```

But, (\w*[^$]) matches every item instead of filtering out the SDI$ and TECHS-NT$ items. What should my regex look like, if not (\w*[^$]) ?

Comment: If they will always end with a $ sign, you just just check for `str.EndsWith("$")` which will be a lot faster.

Comment: I could, but I am exercising my RegEx. That's why I'm asking what is wrong with my RegEx, not "How do I filter out this character".

Comment: In that case, the issue comes from the fact that you have not set delimiters around your regex. This regex essentially say: at least zero word-characters and then not $. But you do not say when to start or stop looking. For instance, in the last line, the regex parser considers SDI$, SDI, SD, S when doing the tests. Try using `@"^(\w*[^$])$"` instead. Also, \w does not cover spaces which will cause the first item to be rejected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex looks a bit weird. If you want to match lines *ending* with a dollar sign, try something like this:

```
\$$
```

Remember that `$` means *end of line/string* in a regex, so to use it it needs to be escaped. If you wish to match any line containg a dollar sign, simply:

```
\$
```

Though, if we could convince you not to use a regex for this, LINQ would be alot easier. Simply:

```
var res = from line in Powershell.Create().AddScript( PS Script )
          where !line.EndsWith( "$" )
          select line;
```

Or:

```
var res = Powershell.Create().AddScript( PS Script ).Where( q => !q.EndsWith( "$" ) );
```

Change `EndsWith` to `Contains` to find any dollar sign, not just ones at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is completely unnecessary here.  Just use the Contains method to see if the string has a $ in it.

```
foreach (string str in Powershell.Create().AddScript(PS Script))
{
    if (!str.Contains("$"))
    {
        powershellResults.Add(str);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex isn't needed here, use IndexOf which returns -1 when not found.

```
  if (str.IndexOf("$")==-1)
   {
        powershellResults.Add(str);
   }
```